# socket.io malfunctionaing on a node.js server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to set up a communication channel between two node servers.

```
.----------.      .----------.
| SERVER A | <--> | SERVER B |
'----------'      '----------'
```

For some reason, the server B acknowledges that a socket has connected but doesn't respond to any events that I try to emit from server A

Server A:

```
var iocli = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = iocli.connect('http://localhost:9000');
// there is some code before here that declares the usertask array and     //connects to a database but none of it is io related        
do {
              var d = new Date().toString();
                if(JSON.stringify(userTasks) != '[]'){
                if(userTasks[0].date.toString() == d){
                  if (state == true){
                  socket.emit('task-due', userTasks[0] )
                  socket.emit('test-task', userTasks[0] )
                  //the message from the line below logs correctly so the lines above must execute too
                  console.log('event is due');
                  state = false
                      }
                }    
              }
              } while(true);
```

Server B:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(9000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  sendTextMessage(admin.fbID, "Got a client connected ")
  socket.on("test-task",function(data){
    sendTextMessage(admin.dbID, "got data "+ JSON.stringify(data))
  })
  socket.on('task-due', function(task){
    if(typeof task.user_id == "string" ){
      task.user_id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data._id);
    }
    User.findOne({
      "_id": task.user_id
    },"fbID",function(err, user){
      if (err) errorHandler(err); 
      if (task.mark){
        sendTextMessage(user.fbID, "One of your tasks is due in !! : "+ task.body + " with a "+task.mark+"marker.")

      }else{
      sendTextMessage(user.fbID, "One of your tasks is due in !! : "+ task.body)
    }
    })
  })
});
```

Any useful insight would be much appreciated

Comment: Your `do { ... } while (true)` is blocking the event loop. I also don't see where in server A you are listening to messages sent from server B.

Comment: @MichalHainc but server A isn't listening to messages sent from server B, and part of the question is that server A _"doesn't respond to any events that I try to emit from server B"_.

Comment: @robertklep sorry I mean that server B is not responding to any events sent from server A. Are you saying that it's because of the while loop that those scripts are not working?

Comment: @SultanKenjeyev most likely, yes. Try to get it working _without_ the while loop first (just one iteration), to see if that works. If so, read up on `setTimeout/setInterval` [here](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html), which you can use to run code periodically.